# Issues on collision detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure why my collision is not causing my console to print out "i hit enemy". Player has a rigidbody component, enemy does not.

My enemy has the `tag` Enemy. Enemy is moving about using transform. My player has the rigid body component, my enemy does not.  Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
public float moveSpeed;
public float maxSpeed = 5f;

private Vector3 input;
private Rigidbody rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

    if (rb.velocity.magnitude < maxSpeed) {
        rb.AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
    }      
}

void onCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        print ("I hit enemy");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: does your enemy object have a collider attached (and the player)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple mistake for new Unity users. Spelling counts! Simply replace `onCollisionEnter` with `OnCollisionEnter`. The callback functions are case sensitive and their first letter is usually **capitalized**.

If changing this does not work, attach Rigidbody to your enemy too. Make sure they both have Colliders attached to both of them and that **IsTrigger** is not `enabled`.

Comment: Thanks! This was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions could fit. Maybe you simply forgot to set the tag on your enemy?
Please have a look at the Unity3D collision matrix (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html - at the bottom of the page).

The collision matrix tells you when you will get collision messages. E.g. you can't have a static collider colliding with a rigidbody collider. Recheck all your gameobjects. Are they fitting the needs of a collision?